# Django OneToMany relationship using ForeignKey queryset

Tags: python, django, database, python-2.7

I use in model in django framework OneToMany relationship using ForeignKey.

That I need now and I don't know how to do it is to create a queryset to take for any id in table Order how ids have as fk key in table Line, that I want to show in html page.

for example I want to show in html template something like this:

```
id_order | id_line
1        |    2
2        | 3,4,8
10       |    7
```

that confused me because I think we need to reverse foreign key.

Here's the model :

```
django.db import models

class Order(models.Model):
    order_name = models.CharField(max_length=254)

class Line(models.Model):
    f= models.ForeignKey(Order, blank=True, null=True,verbose_name='order')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose to in **Order** table data:

```
id  order_name
1   order 1
2   order 2
10  order 10
```

**Line** table data:

```
id  name    f_id
2   line 2  1
3   line 3  2
4   line 4  2
7   line 1  10
8   line 5  2
```

Then I run following query

```
lines = Line.objects.select_related('order').values('f_id', 'id')
```

It will return following results:

```
<QuerySet [{'f_id': 1, 'id': 2}, {'f_id': 2, 'id': 3}, {'f_id': 2, 'id': 4}, {'f_id': 2, 'id': 8}, {'f_id': 10, 'id': 7}]>
```

`select_related` returns a QuerySet that will “follow” foreign-key relationships, selecting additional related-object data when it executes its query.

**Update:**
In template

```
{% for line in lines %}
    <p>{{ line.f_id.name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: how to use that query in html template ?